# readdir excludes some files in a directory

Tags: c++, dirent.h

I have a fairly simple piece of code to get a list of files in a directory in C++. Inexplicably, only 68 of 135 files in the directory end up being stored in the vector fileNames. What is happening?

```
DIR* pDIR = opendir(directoryName.c_str());
  struct dirent* entry = nullptr;

  vector<string> fileNames;

  while(readdir(pDIR)) {
    entry = readdir(pDIR);
    if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0 )
      fileNames.push_back(entry->d_name);
  }
  closedir(pDIR);
```

Comment: You call readdir() twice, but only handle one of the results, so you miss half of the files ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing *readdir* 2 times for every iteration. So, you are skipping the half of files.

The fix is easy, just call one time:

```
DIR* pDIR = opendir(directoryName.c_str());
  struct dirent* entry = nullptr;

  vector<string> fileNames;

  while(entry = readdir(pDIR)) {
    if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0 )
      fileNames.push_back(entry->d_name);
  }
  closedir(pDIR);
```